# Browsing web site from own server does not work - but does externally

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, windows, iis-8

I have a brand new install of Windows Server 2012 with IIS 8 on a colocated box. I moved the InetPub folder to D:\ using the script [here](http://blogs.iis.net/thomad/archive/2008/02/10/moving-the-iis7-inetpub-directory-to-a-different-drive.aspx).

I set a domain to point to the server.

I added a new website with the machine's IP address and the domain as the host name

When I go to that web site from the local server (using the domain name) I get the default web site, not the new one with that host name configured. Btw, DNS propagation is done.

However, when I browse to that domain from my dev machine, I get a 404 error. If I explicitly go to the default page on my new site (index.html) it displays.

So two issues here (are they related?):

1. Local machine seems hared wired to go to the stock default web site (i.e No IP address or host name assigned.)
2. The default document feature is not working on new web site. I verified it is enabled.

I will also post the default document issue separately (with its own Title) in case it is not in any way related.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you stop the default website? Sounds like the bindings are in need of adjustment.

Comment: Then I get a 404 error. My first suspect was also the bindings, but they are correct to best of my knowledge. And they work external from the server.

Comment: I got the default document problem fixed. See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899450/iis8-default-document-yields-404-not-found-error/) for my answer.

Comment: If I change the IP address of the new website to All Unassigned rather than the IP address of the server, it works.

Comment: It has to do with local DNS resolving to different IP than in IIS bindings perhaps